# How can I get all partial matches using Get-ADComputer filter?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wildcard

I have following PowerShell script

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like $computerhost}
write-host $server.name
```

It gives me the ADComputer that contains `$computerhost` in it's name.

Example:

```
$computerhost = linuxserver
```

matching computer name output: "linuxserver01"

---

But I actually want the ADComputer if a name of a computer fits inside `$computerhost`. So if $computerhost is "asdf" I wanna get the computer with the name "a" or "as" or "asd" or "asdf", but not "asda"

Example:

```
$computerhost = linuxserver (new)
```

matching computer name output: "linuxserver"

---

I have no idea how to use wildcards in that way.

Comment: _But I actually want the ADComputer, that fits inside $computerhost._ I actually dont know what you mean by that? You only want to search for a partial name from `$computerhost`? How do you decide what to remove then?

Comment: If a name of a computer in the AD fits inside $computerhost. So if $computerhost is "asdf" I wanna get the computer with the name "a" or "as" or "asd" or "asdf", but not "asda" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying via the comments. I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | where-object { $computerhost -like "*$($_.name)*" }
```

For example (i'm using $computers here in place of get-adcomputer):

```
$computers = 'a','as','asd','asdf','asda'
$computerhost = 'asdf'

$computers | where-object { $computerhost -like "*$_*" }
```

Returns:

> a
>
> as
>
> asd
>
> asdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

This works, if I have a list of all the computers outside the Active Directory. Do I have to create a list with all computers from the AD or is there a simple way to do this directly with the AD?

Comment: @Dave494 That is what the first line of code in this answer is for. The second is proof of concept

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for partial matches to your string `$computerHost` filter will not handle that since it does not properly translate to a LDAP query. You would have to process that filter after returning all computers in you selection set. You parameters like `-SearchScope` to reduce that if you have a large computer base. Simplest approach is to use `.contains()`

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | Where-Object{$computerhost.contains($_.name)}
```

Need to be careful as `.contains()` is case sensitive. One thing you could do is force both your string to the same case to remove that issue.

```
Where-Object{$computerhost.ToUpper().contains($_.name.toUpper())}
```

Can also use `-match` operatore just beware that it supports regex. That should not be an issue here but if your computer names have hyphens they will need to be escaped.

```
Where-Object{$_.name -match $computerhost}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Matt. I just tried this with an existing computer and added asdf to it. Didn't work. Tried it with an existing computer without adding anything. Didn't work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: No need to, already got it. Gotta do it like this: Get-ADComputer -filter * | where-object { $computerhost -like "*$($_.name)*" }   Thank you anyways